# Update an interactive graph on Bokeh using a dropdown and callback

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I'm very new to Python but have been following DataCamp training. I am hoping to update a graph using a dropdown menu.

The dropdown menu will select a column from the dataframe, and plot that data on the x-axis.

This is what i have so far:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/PStuff/dataA.txt')
source = ColumnDataSource(df1)

plot = figure()
plot.circle(x = 'col1', y = 'col5', source=source)

menu = Select(options=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], value='col1', title='Distribution')

def callback(attr, old, new):
    if menu.value == 'col2':  x ='col2'
    elif menu.value == 'col3': x ='col3'
    else:                       x ='col1'
menu.on_change('value', callback)

layout = column(menu, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

I am not currently receiving any errors in running it or running Bokeh serve, at the moment simply nothing shows up! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's working and what isn't working? Have you tried debugging or adding logs to see the value or the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x`from the plot.circle() arguments only exist within that call. So your callback is just assigning a value to an `x` variable that does nothing.

You can update the source itself.

```
# set the source to specific columns from df1 initially
source = ColumnDataSoruce(data={'x':df1['col1'],'y':df1['col5']}) 
plot.circle(x = 'x', y = 'y', source=source)
menu = Select(options=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], value='col1', title='Distribution')
def callback(attr, old, new):
   source.data.update({'x':df1[new]})
```